# anyone can explain why mysql does not use index as expected

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

**MYSQL 5.7**

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT biz.id as id, AVG(case WHEN req.deploy_date_id > 0 THEN 
req.dev_cost_time_ex_holiday ELSE null END) as test
FROM t_fact_fit_req as req, t_dim_business as biz, t_dim_deploy_date as d
WHERE req.biz_id = biz.id
AND req.deploy_date_id = d.id
AND biz.id in (10)
AND d.id BETWEEN 20210605 AND 20210611
GROUP BY biz.id
```

[image]
there is index idx_biz_date_req_type **(biz_id, deploy_date_id, req_type)** on **req**, why it is not been used ?

Comment: I can guess that perhaps a significantly large portion of the rows in `req` all have the same `biz_id` equal to 10. So the optimizer estimates that it would be no savings to use the index.

Comment: Another possibility is that the table statistics are not accurate, so the optimizer doesn't know that the index would be helpful. You should run `ANALYZE TABLE` on each of these tables to ensure the statistics are current. This is safe to do on a table without blocking other clients.

Comment: @BillKarwin did analyze, same result, and biz_id = 10 count for 4682

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the real reason for this is **data type** in query

`req.biz_id` is `varchar` while `biz.id` is `int`

so the sql of `WHERE req.biz_id = biz.id` should be
`WHERE req.biz_id = CAST(biz.id AS CHAR)`

then index used

Comment: This is why it's important to share the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of each table in your query when you ask for query optimization help. You should not expect readers to guess at the data types of your columns, but it might include important details for the optimization.

Comment: @BillKarwin that's true, that is a huge table, so i missed

Answer (score 1):

Aside from being an auto-generated query, the `biz` and `d` tables are not even required as the `biz_id` and `deploy_date_id` are part of your `req` table and dont require the additional correlation to the other tables as you are not getting anything from them.  This simplifies down to below query.

```
SELECT 
        req.biz_id id, 
        AVG(case WHEN req.deploy_date_id > 0 
                THEN req.dev_cost_time_ex_holiday 
                ELSE null END) as test
    FROM 
        t_fact_fit_req req
    where
            req.biz_id = 10
        AND req.deploy_date_id BETWEEN 20210605 AND 20210611
```

As for indexes, you mentioned a date field in your `req` table, but your WHERE clause is looking at your `d` table

Due to transitive association, if A = B and B = C, then A = C.  Since you have respective A/B and B/C values within the B common, and that is where data is coming from, you dont need A or C.  your `Req` table has all you need for the query.

So, in this scenario, if you change your date test from the d.id date criteria to the req.deploy_date_id criteria, the index SHOULD get used.  But as you mentioned about the query being generated, I would have to look into the logic of how THAT is being built.

Comment: not what i'm looking for, but still inspired me to find the answer, thx, I will put the reason here

Answer (score 0):

Because it's no longer 1992, we'd normally write that query this way:

```
SELECT b.id 
     , AVG(CASE WHEN r.deploy_date_id > 0 THEN 
r.dev_cost_time_ex_holiday ELSE NULL END)  test
  FROM t_fact_fit_req r
  JOIN t_dim_business b
    ON b.id =  r.biz_id 
  JOIN t_dim_deploy_date d
    ON d.id = r.deploy_date_id 
 WHERE b.id IN (10)
   AND d.id BETWEEN 20210605 AND 20210611
 GROUP 
    BY b.id
```

While this does nothing for performance, I find it easier to read.

As to the problem at hand, wouldn't this be more efficient?

```
AVG(r.dev_cost_time_ex_holiday)  test
  ...
 WHERE r.deploy_date_id > 0
```

Comment: it's an auto generated sql. my point is which i asked

Comment: Normally where a column is called 'id', it's assumed to have a cardinality of one. In an index containing that column, any columns after that must be redundant.